# Why can't you discard a question, only a draft?

Tags: feature-request, questions, draft

If you close a tab with an un-posted question, it is saved as a draft for next time you come back. Handy, but often I answer my question in the process of writing it and don't want to save it. Next time I have a question I then have to discard or delete my draft before starting. **I would like to suggest the option to discard a question while writing it.**

Also - you get a modal "Leave Site?" popup if you try to close a tab with a draft - but since it saves your question this seems superfluous to a degree.

Comment: I'm not sure what such a feature would achieve that CTRL+A followed by pressing the Delete key wouldn't...?

Comment: What should actually be discarded, if it didn't even affect the repository yet? Can you elaborate about that please?

Comment: So you've voted down my question and voted to close it, but also highly up-voted an answer which seems to suggest it is inconsistent behavior?

Comment: @Jenayah well yes who needs a good UI. MS Word should clearly expect users who don't want to save a document to use the same mechanism? Also - if I have filled in title, question body and tags do I have to delete all or only some... it's not clear. Not to mention any images I uploaded are perhaps saved on the server (not sure on this, maybe a separate bug if so)

Comment: As a feature request, it already exists.  FWIW, I did attempt to edit the question title in order to make it more clear what you were asking but the edit was rejected.  That rejection is what spurred the research into the matter and what created the bug report that followed.  I can't speak for the down voters, but you did play a role in the discovery of these issues.  The second part about the popup I tend to agree with, if only because I despise unnecessary popups.

Answer (score 8):

<strike>You cannot discard a question draft while you are writing it or are about to leave</strike> (read edit).  You are able to discard a question draft after you return to it later just the same as you are able to do with an answer you return to later, as circled here:

> [image: After returning to a question draft, Discard is available]

The difference is that it doesn't appear to save the draft of the question and give you the option to discard it before you leave the page the same way that the answers do.

---

I propose that feedback be given to the user posting a question similarly as to a user posting an answer: Show that the draft has been saved (something that it does not do, and I did not know that question drafts were even saved until researching this), and allow the user to delete the draft while writing the question.

**Edit**: Upon doing research I have found that it does do the above, however it requires certain criteria to be met.  I have detailed what I have found [in a bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344154/questions-not-showing-draft-saved).