# Questions not showing "draft saved" message

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions, draft

While doing some research about [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344149/why-cant-you-discard-a-question-only-a-draft) I discovered a few bugs related to the feedback you receive when posting a question.  The user in that question presumably wants to be able to do the same thing that you can do while writing an answer and discard the draft *before* leaving the page.

I have learned that you are able to do this; But there are odd qualifiers that don't seem to be purposely designed that way.  I've detailed my testing below.

---

How tests were performed:

- Title: "Title only question title"
- Body: Hand typing (not copy-pasting) repeating `1234567890` (with a single trailing space) to get character counts
- Tags: `discussion`

---

### Case #1: Title Only

If you type in a title only that meets the minimum requirements, the screen will not show that a draft has been saved.  A draft does save and if you refresh it will save the title that you had.  However in this situation, while it is a draft, the ability to discard is not available.

### Case #2: Returning to title only question draft

If you type a title only, then leave the page and come back (or refresh) the title is preserved, however after typing between 74-122 it will show draft saved (seems to either be timed or triggered by characters but time and characters are inconsistent, can do further testing to narrow down but the jist is here), and allows to discard the draft.

### Case #3: Body Only

After typing 165 characters (first test) into the question body it shows that the draft has been saved and allows for the question's draft to be deleted.  If you type less than that (say 32 characters), it does not show that a draft has been saved after a long pause, however upon leaving and returning to the page the draft is shown and is able to be discarded.

For comparison purposes, if you type 32 characters into an answer and stop typing for a period of time, it will give you the visual feedback of the draft being saved along with the discard option

### Case #4: Tags only

When you only add a tag, there is no draft saved indicator or ability to discard.  Upon refreshing, the tags have saved in the draft, however there is no option to discard.  Adding multiple tags (`bug` and `support`) did not change behavior.

### Case #5: Title and Body

A title and 177 characters (first test) provided draft saved feedback and the ability to discard.  Leaving 32 characters in the body and long pausing did not trigger the draft saved feedback.  Refreshing with 32 characters shows that it saved the draft and allows to discard.

### Case #6: Tags and Title

Entering tags then entering a title does not trigger draft saved or discard options.  Refreshing shows that both title and tags are saved however does not give you the option to discard the draft.

### Case #7: Tags and Body

Adding tags then typing 171 characters (first test) triggered draft saved and allowed to discard draft.  Typing 32 characters and long pausing does not trigger draft saved message.  When refreshing, both have the previous draft and the ability to discard.

---

A long pause triggers the message and the ability to delete an answer, I request that this functionality be migrated to the question side of posting as well.  After adding a tag it should show the message as well.  The tag and titles not showing discard option even after a returning to a draft can certainly be a nuisance.